# python variable lambda expression shortcut method for sorted expression

Tags: python, lambda

The following code works but it's very ungainly:

```py
        a = 0
        for k in keys:
            a = a + 1
            if a == 1:
                k1 = k
            if a == 2:
                k2 = k
            if a == 3:
                k3 = k
        if a == 1:
            list_of_dict = sorted(list_of_dict, key = lambda ele: ele[k1], reverse = rev)
        if a == 2:
            list_of_dict = sorted(list_of_dict, key = lambda ele: ele[k1][k2], reverse = rev)
        if a == 3:
            list_of_dict = sorted(list_of_dict, key = lambda ele: ele[k1][k2][k3], reverse = rev)
```

My question is if there is any way to express this more succinctly. (note, `reverse` references the [unshown] variable `rev`, so I figured there must be a way to do the same with `ele`)

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: is sorts a list of `dict` objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be implemented with closures:

```
def nested_itemgetter(keys):
    def getter(val):
        for key in keys:
            val = val[key]
        return val
    return getter
```

Or class:

```
class NestedItemGetter:
    def __init__(self, keys):
        self.keys = keys

    def __call__(self, val):
        for key in self.keys:
            val = val[key]
        return val
```

Usage:

```
list_of_dict = sorted(list_of_dict, key=nested_itemgetter(keys), reverse=rev)
list_of_dict = sorted(list_of_dict, key=NestedItemGetter(keys), reverse=rev)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
from functools import partial


def nested_itemgetter(ks, d):
    res = d
    for key in ks:
        res = res[key]
    return res


rev = True
list_of_dict = [{"a": {"b": {"c": 1}}}, {"a": {"b": {"c": 2}}}, {"a": {"b": {"c": 3}}}]

keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
res = sorted(list_of_dict, key=partial(nested_itemgetter, keys), reverse=rev)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'a': {'b': {'c': 3}}}, {'a': {'b': {'c': 2}}}, {'a': {'b': {'c': 1}}}]
```

Comment: If you want to be even more funcy: [key=partial(reduce, getitem, keys)](https://tio.run/##dY9BC4JAEIXv8ysGTwl7qS4R@C@6hYitYy2pu8yOQoS/3UZLCKLLG/je25154SE33@0PgaepZt9i3XdWvG8iujZ4Fgwliysbg0xVbwmWlA/EpXheQ1cSJ9QCANOAGZ64J2hclMLXReWsKDs/kzI54jO5LGpVt@M4Gvzluz98rzwHuNMjzh@qb1BtFZvkunqmUe@havO93KC@yD5FNu8eZr15MWM69xuII2U6U4DArhPNxnSaXg)